# Surface Area Configuration - component is turned off as part of the security configuration for this server

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, sql-server-job

I'm getting this error when running a SQL Server job:

> Description: Executing the query "EXEC Stgs.sp_SendEmail ?" failed with the following error: "SQL Server blocked access to procedure 'dbo.sp_send_dbmail' of component 'Database Mail XPs' because this component is turned off as part of the security configuration for this server. A system administrator can enable the use of 'Database Mail XPs' by using sp_configure. For more information about enabling 'Database Mail XPs', see "Surface Area Configuration" in SQL Server Books Online.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  6:24:54 PM  Finished: 6:40:10 PM  Elapsed:  915.867 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.

The error description shows two confusing things.

1st, its saying,Security configuration issue.
2nd, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly

How to get what the actual error could be? What could be the resolution?
Please suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'Database Mail XPs', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

The [setting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms191189.aspx) takes effect immediately without a server stop and restart.